# Calculate singular value decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I need to find the reduced singular value decomposition of this matrix.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & -2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I formed 
$$
A^TA=
\begin{pmatrix}
8 & 4 & -8 \\
4 & 2 & -4 \\
-8 & -4 & 8 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Found the eigenvalue 18 and eigenvector 
$$\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -1/2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$
u_1=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{3\sqrt2}{4} \\ \frac{-3\sqrt2}{4} \end{pmatrix}
$$

So
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{3\sqrt2}{4} \\ \frac{-3\sqrt2}{4} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3\sqrt2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1/2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

But this is clearly not correct

Comment: Why stop at one eigenvalue/eigenvector?

Comment: The other was zero. My book says to not include them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

This is a rank $2$ matrix,  your computation of $A^TA$ is wrong.

```
octave:1> A = [-2 -1 1; 2 1 -2]
A =

  -2  -1   1
   2   1  -2

octave:2> A'*A
ans =

   8   4  -6
   4   2  -3
  -6  -3   5
```

Also, rather than dealing with $A^TA$, perhaps working with $AA^T$ is simpler.

Edit:

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} -2 & -1 & 2 \\2 & 1 & -2\end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} -2 & -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \\
&=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \\ -\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}3\sqrt{2}\begin{bmatrix} -\frac23 & -\frac13 & \frac23 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Singular vectors are of unit length.

Comment: Sorry just realized I typed the wrong number in A. I updated the question

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: How did you get [-2/3 -1/3 2/3]?

Comment: Just normalize the vector.

Comment: I guess my book is very vague on this. If there were multiple singular vectors would you just normalize each one or apply Gram-Schmidt to them? Same for the eigenvectors?

Comment: Gram-Schmidt, of which part of the procedure involve normalization.